# How long is a beat in seconds?

Tags: sheet-music, rhythm

I wanna make a Minecraft noteblock song, and don't know how long a beat is in seconds (4/4). I know that 10 redstone ticks are in one second. I can use repeaters as rests, but I need to set the delay of the repeaters, and I can't make rests if I don't know how long a beat is, so please help me.

Edit: By the way everytime you right-click a repeater, the delay increases by 1 redstone tick. The delay is set to 1 redstone tick (or 0.1 seconds) by default. If you right click it after the delay reaches four redstone ticks, it goes back to one redstone tick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you need meter in music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11124/why-do-you-need-meter-in-music)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 120 BPM (beats per minute), which is a typical pop song tempo, every beat lasts half a second. Divide 60 by the BPM to get the length of a beat at other tempos. You can use the [Google metronome](https://google.com/search?q=metronome) to try out tempos expressed in BPM.

if I understand your explanation correctly, you can set the timing of the notes and rests in tenths of a second. This is the tempo of the music in BPM for different lengths of beats (quarter notes):

```
Seconds  BPM

  0.3    200
  0.4    150
  0.5    120
  0.6    100
  0.7     85.71
  0.8     75
  0.9     66.66
  1.0     60
```

If you want to sub-divide the beats into shorter notes and rests, you will have to choose a tempo at which you can evenly divide the quarter notes; e.g. if you choose beats of 0.6 seconds at 100BPM, you can use eighth notes of 0.3 seconds and eighth note triplets of 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The length of a beat depends on tempo, and tempo depends on the style and feeling that's wanted. Or the other way around - whatever beat length you set, it sets a tempo and a feeling. If your beat is one second long, then you get 60 of them per minute, and the tempo is 60 beats per minute.

Try different tempos and see what you like.